# How Can I Set Dropzone Thumbnail on Element That is Clicked for Browse File?

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I have one element as a dropzone and another one is an instance of it; both are clickable for browsing the file.

I want to set thumbnail to them based on which one I clicked on it for browsing file. For example, if I click on element A to browse the file, then I would like to set a thumbnail to an element A. Likewise, if I click on element B to browse the file, then I would like to set a thumbnail to an element B.

Here is what I have tried, but it did not work:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var previewTemplate = document.querySelector('#tpl').innerHTML;
  var default_option = {
    url: '/upload',
    method: "post",
    autoProcessQueue: false,
    uploadMultiple: true,
    maxFiles: 2,
    parallelUploads: 100,
    thumbnailWidth: 80,
    thumbnailHeight: 80,
    timeout: 0,
    previewsContainer: '.row-thumbnail',
    previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
    clickable: '.a, .b'
  }
  var myUploadObj = new Dropzone('#myDz', default_option);

});
```

```css
.upload-container {
  display: flex;
}

.a,
.b {
  width: 325px;
  height: 325px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.7.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<div class="upload-container">
  <div class="a" id="myDz">
    <div class="dz-message"><span>Element A</span></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row-thumbnail dropzone-previews b">
    <div class="dz-message"><span>Element B</span></div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- preview template -->
<div id="tpl" style="display: none;">
  <div class="dz-preview dz-file-preview thumbnail-item">
    <div class="dz-image"><img data-dz-thumbnail /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes to your code and tested it out in this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/go3atv6n/)
I think the concept you want to achieve is changing the css property of an element when it is clicked .
If you don't want to play with the **css** *background-image* property you can always use the *:before* or *:after* property to append data before or after your tag (element).
This is the main function responsible for this behavior in the fiddle

```
$('.class To Be Clicked').click(function() {
    $('.class to be changed').css({
        "background-image": "url('url to image here')"
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not doing with background image, I want to set the thumbnail of image after I browse to choose image. The thumbnail should appear in the element A or B that was click for browsing the image. Thanks

Comment: Okay so you want to set the **uploaded** image to be the thumbnail of the element am I correct ? like this [https://cdn.cms-twdigitalassets.com/content/dam/help-twitter/en/twitter-tips/desktop-assets/chapter-5/ch-5-2-photo-button.png.twimg.1920.png] for example ?

Comment: Yeah, currently I can set thumbnail already, as you can test my code in the question, but the thumbnail only goes to the element B and never A. I want it to show thumbnail on A if I click on A, and B if I click on B. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The preview container is determined by the previewsContainer property in the dropzone object. You can take a look at the related source code here -
https://github.com/dropzone/dropzone/blob/main/src/dropzone.js
line 147 - 156

So you just need to set previewsContainer dynamically whenever a or b is clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
              var previewTemplate = document.querySelector('#tpl').innerHTML;
              var default_option = {
                url: '/upload',
                method: "post",
                autoProcessQueue: false,
                uploadMultiple: true,
                maxFiles: 2,
                parallelUploads: 100,
                thumbnailWidth: 80,
                thumbnailHeight: 80,
                timeout: 0,
                previewsContainer: '.row-thumbnail',
                previewTemplate: previewTemplate,
                clickable: '.a, .b'
              }
              var myUploadObj = new Dropzone('#myDz', default_option);
              
              $(".a").on("click", function(){
                myUploadObj.previewsContainer = document.getElementById("myDz");
              });
              $(".b").on("click", function(){
                myUploadObj.previewsContainer = document.getElementById("preview_b");
              });
            });
```

To keep it simple, I added id to b:

```
<div class="row-thumbnail dropzone-previews b" id="preview_b">
```

That is it.
Tested in chrome, works fine.